# How do I make a full screen background image that can be translated without gaps

Tags: flutter

This creates a full screen background image that can be moved with margin, but it creates a blank sliver on the bottom.

```
          Container(
            margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 50),
            child: Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: snapshot.data.color,
                image: DecorationImage(
                  image: AssetImage("assets/overlay.png"),
                  fit: BoxFit.cover,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
```

How can I create a full screen background image that is slightly larger than the viewport and be able to move it around without any clipping or gaps?

Comment: "Move around"? With an animation? Using gesture detection? Please be more specific

Answer (score 0):

This is an example code of how to set full background image try this

```
return new Container(
  child: new Stack(
    children: <Widget>[
     new Container(
       decoration: BoxDecoration(
//             color: snapshot.data.color,
         image: DecorationImage(
//               image: AssetImage("assets/overlay.png"),
              image: NetworkImage('http://www.vactualpapers.com/web/images/April-28-2016/Glitters%20in%20the%20Air%20HD%20Mobile%20Wallpaper.jpg'),
           fit: BoxFit.cover,
         ),
       ),
     ),
      new Scaffold(
        appBar: new AppBar(
          title: new Text('Full Background img'),
          backgroundColor: const Color(0xFF121F2B),
        ),
        backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
        body: new Center(
          child: new Text('Hello How are you?', 
            style: new TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0, color: Colors.white),),
        ),
      )
    ],
  ),
);
```